# mapping through an array doesn't work?

Tags: react-native

when I run the following code the result is a blank screen!

```
render() {
    let num = 0, Qs = [Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5, Q6];
    console.log('hey');
    return <View>
        {Qs.forEach(q => {
            console.log('hey there');
            return <View>
                <Text>asdf</Text>
            </View>})
        }
    </View>
}
```

but the console gets one 'hey' with 6 'hey there' following. weird!

P.S. previously this problem happened while using 'forEach' on an array, then I changed the 'forEach' to 'map' and it was solved.

P.S. 2: do you recommend me to issue a bug report on react-native at GitHub?

Comment: can you share AnswerCard Component?

Comment: the problem occurs even without the 'answerCard' component. Actually, I didn't want to post it in the question, so I change the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React js component, map works, foreach doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460357/react-js-component-map-works-foreach-doesnt)