# How to Dynamically Render Cards in React Semantic UI

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I've mapped my redux store to props, but I'm now having trouble rendering it dynamically. I've also tried `projectCards(){...}` syntax, but that was a total shot in the dark. My console logs are showing the objects coming through the way I want them. I also tried using `projects.map`, but I don't think I want to put the return values in a new array. I just want more `<Card/>` items on the page, dynamically rendered. Where have I gone wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

```
Class Projects extends...
.
.
.
 projectCards = () => {
  if ( this.props.projects.length !== 0 ) {
   this.props.projects.forEach((project) => {
     return <Card fluid color='green' header={project.name} />
  })
 }
}

 render(){
  return(
    <Container>
      <br/>
      <Card.Group>
        <Card fluid color='green' header='Option 1' />
        <Card fluid color='blue' header='Option 2' />
        <Card fluid color='red' header='Option 3' />
        { this.projectCards() }
      </Card.Group>
    </Container>
  )
 }
}
```

Comment: Use `.map()` instead of `.forEach()`. Some past, helpful StackOverflow answers on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47442462/reactjs-map-works-but-foreach-doesnt, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42460357/react-js-component-map-works-foreach-doesnt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
projectCards = () => {
  if ( this.props.projects.length !== 0 ) {
    return this.props.projects.map( project => 
       <Card fluid color='green' header={project.name} />
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: It worked! So I wanted to return an array of `<Card>`s?

Comment: Got it! However, do you think that it's possible to make the function return value more than one time? After returning the first `Card component`, it's done! The other Card components won't have a chance to come to life. Btw, why don't you want to `return an array of <Card>s`

Comment: That's a good point. Not the first time I've tried multiple return statements in the same function today!

Comment: I can't edit it, but there's a curly missing in your post. Thanks for your help.